# The form of a solution in a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this linear system:

$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
2x + 3y - 4z = \ 1 \\
3x -  y - 2z = 2 \\
 x - 7y - 6z = 0
\end{array}\right.$

I found the following solution:

$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha \frac{10}{11}+\frac{7}{11} \\
\alpha \frac{8}{11}-\frac{1}{11} \\
\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
$

but the correct solution is

$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
10t+7\\
8t+5 \\
11t+7
\end{pmatrix}
$

I know that the two solution are equivalent (and correct). Assuming that i don't know the second form, how i can transform the first form into the last form (with only integer coefficents)?

Answer (score 3):

just conveniently look at $z$ and you see 
$$z=\alpha=11t+7$$
If you substitute this for $\alpha$ in the first form, you get the second form. You may also invert this relationship between $t,\alpha$ to get
$$t = \frac{\alpha-7}{11} $$
If you substitute to the second form, you get the first form.

Comment: Of course. But if i don't know the second form how i can linearize the solution?

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand this question. What does it mean to "linearize the solution"?

Comment: I mean that the solution must have only integer coefficients

Comment: I see, that was my guess that this is what you wanted. Well, if you had your form only, you would first make the coefficients of $\alpha$ integer by writing $\alpha = 11\beta$ where $11$ was found as the smallest common multiple of the denominators. That would yield $(x,y,z) = (10\beta+7/11,8\beta-1/11,11\beta)$. Then you would shift $\beta$ in such a way that the absolute coefficients are also integer.

Comment: You want to shift $\beta$ by a multiple of $1/11$, by $k/11$, that makes the absolute coefficients integer as well. $10k+7$ and $8k-1$ have to be a multiple of $11$. $k=7$ just does the job but that's not the only solution: $k=-4$ or any $11n-4$ does the job, too.